# The pdf of $X+Y$

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, uniform-distribution

$X,Y$ are independent. $X\sim U(0,1)$ and 
$$f_Y(y)=\cases{2y,\;0<y<1\\ 0,\;Else.}$$
What is the pdf of $X+Y$? (i.e. $f_{X+Y}$)

I know that
$$f_X(x)=\cases{1,\;0<x<1\\ 0,\;Else.}$$ But how I continue from here?
Thank you!!

Comment: it may be helpful to note that $Y\sim Beta(2,1)$ and $X\sim Beta(1,1)$ from this you jus have sum of 2 independent beta distributions

Comment: @user159813, what is $Beta(2,1)$?? We didn't learn it so I can't use it...

Comment: Sometimes it helps to find the cumulative distribution first. That is, find $F_{X+Y}$.  If you are able to do that, then you can use the fact that the pdf is the derivative of the cdf.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The pdf of $Z=X+Y$ is the convolution of $f_X$ and $f_Y$:
$$f_Z(z) = \int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}f_X(x)\,f_Y(z-x)dx = \int_{0}^{1}f_Y(z-x)\,dx = \int_{z-1}^{z}f_Y(x)\,dx,$$
hence:
$$f_Z(x)=\left\{\begin{array}{ll}x^2 &\mbox{when } x\in[0,1]\\2x-x^2 &\mbox{when } x\in[1,2]\\0&\mbox{otherwise}.\end{array}\right.$$

Comment: How do you get the final answer? and where $f_X(x)$ disappear? Your answer is great but if you can explain more it will be great!! Thank you!!

Comment: $f_X(x)$ "disappears" because $f_X$ is just one between $0$ and $1$. For a similar reason, the last integral is $\int_{0}^{z}2x\,dx$ when $z\in[0,1]$ and $\int_{z-1}^{1}2x\,dx$ when $z\in[1,2]$.

Comment: And why $2x-x^2,\; x\in[1,2]$ how do you get it and how do you get the range? Thank you so much!

Comment: $\int_{x-1}^{1}2t\,dt = 1-(x-1)^2 = 2x-x^2.$ The integration range comes from the previous comment.

Comment: Perhaps it helps you to think of it as follows: Letting $1_A$ denote the indicator function of the set $A$, $\int_{z-1}^z f_Y(x)dx=\int_{z-1}^z 2x1_{(0,1)}(x)dx = \int_{[z-1,z]\cap (0,1)} 2x dx$. So we always integrate $2x$, but the range over which we integrate depends on $z$ and is $[z-1,z]\cap (0,1)$. Now if $z>0$ is at most one, the intersection of the two intervals is $(0,z)$, if $1\leq z\leq 2$, the intersection is $[z-1,1)$ and for $z>2$ the intersection is empty.